# TYPO3 8.7 - FSC gallery: alter row / column dimensions

Tags: typo3, gallery, typoscript, fluid-styled-content

I want to generate an image-matrix width 5 columns and n rows. My inner content is a container with a fluid width, but max 680px. Therefore the images inside each row have to have a max width of 136px.

If I choose 5 columns in the Gallery Settings of the default content element type "Images", the image-element in the frontend is rendered with a width of 112px. (112 x 5 = 560)

Unfortunately I can't find a constant or setup variable where this value is stored.

May you guys point me in the right direction?

I'm also using fluid_styled_content.

Cheers,
Mario

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Here is a list of some constants that could be set:**

```
styles.content.textmedia.maxW
```

This indicates that maximum number of pixels (width) a block of media elements inserted as content is allowed to consume

```
styles.content.textmedia.maxWInText
```

Same as above, but this is the maximum width when text is wrapped around an block of media elements. Default is 50% of the normal Max Media Item Width

```
styles.content.textmedia.linkWrap.width
```

This specifies the width of the enlarged media element when click-enlarge is enabled

```
styles.content.textmedia.linkWrap.height
```

This specifies the height of the enlarged media element when click-enlarge is enabled

```
styles.content.textmedia.columnSpacing
```

Horizontal distance between media elements in a block in content elements of type "Media & Images". If you change this manually in your CSS, you need to adjust this setting accordingly

```
styles.content.textmedia.rowSpacing
```

Vertical distance after each media elements row in content elements of type ""Text & Media". If you change this manually in your CSS, you need to adjust this setting accordingly

**For more information**

Open the "Template"-Module, select "Constant Editor" and "CONTENT"

Comment: **Perfect!** Kevin, you made my day!

Comment: Is it possible to use different values depending on the colPos of a content element?